# Recursively remove files with idx > 10,000

Tags: shell, shell-script, find, quoting

## The problem

In the current *working directory* I have several (very many) folders and some of them have lots (like 100,000+) of files inside.

My goal is getting just the folder with 10,000+ files and delete `folderName10001.ext` and above (where `folderName` is the actual name of the containing folder and `ext` is a *whatever* extension).

## Approach taken

I am trying to print `nameFolder numberOfFiles` with `bash`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec sh -c "echo {}; ls {} | wc -l" \;
```

This works just fine (for the sample folder `acer`), but the output is

```
./acer
6058
```

I would like to have 1-line output per folder

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec sh -c "echo {} `ls {} | wc -l`" \;
```

says `ls: cannot access {}: No such file or directory`.

---

## Questions

1. How can I get to display in one line `nameFolder numberOfFiles`?
2. Is there an easier way to delete every file `folderName/folderName#.ext`, with `#` > `10000`?

### Question 2

Some more details may help understand what's going on.

I have a folder with the following tree

```
.
├── a
│   ├── a1.ext
│   ├── a2.ext
│   ├── a3.ext
│   └── a4.ext
├── b
│   ├── b1.ext
│   ├── b2.ext
│   ├── b3.ext
│   └── b4.ext
└── c
    ├── c1.ext
    ├── c2.ext
    ├── c3.ext
    └── c4.ext
```

I'd like to remove every file with a number greater than `2`. (In my specific case the threshold is set to `10000`.)

---

## Answer 1

It's all about *who* interprets *what* (thanks to [**@Bratchley**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34520/bratchley) for the advise in the comments).

Since I'm typing into `bash`, `bash` gets first to interpret what I type.
If I want `bash` to send to `find`'s `bash` a *backtick*, then I need to *escape* it.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec sh -c "echo {} \`ls {} | wc -l;\`" \;
```

which gives me

```
./acer 6058
```

[**@Barmar**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/61098/barmar) [points out that *single-* and *double-quotes* behaves differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194284/38879), and therefore

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec sh -c 'echo {} `ls {} | wc -l`' \;
```

would work just fine (note `"` replaced with `'`).

## Answer 2

This has been provided by [**Walter A**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/57293/walter-a), and it is the *accepted answer* for this question.

More errors (a couple of examples follows)...

```
black: 390120
./clean.sh: line 6: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

leather: 118240
./clean.sh: line 6: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

OK, I've fixed it with

```
ls -d */ | cut -d/ -f1 | while read dir; do
COUNT=$(ls $dir | wc -l);
   if [ ${COUNT} -gt 10000 ]; then
      echo "$dir: ${COUNT}" ;
      for i in `seq 10001 ${COUNT}`; do
         rm ${dir}/${dir}${i}.*
      done
   fi
done
```

Comment: working on the second question but the first one would involve giving `echo` the `-n` option.

Comment: Does something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "echo {} \$(ls {} | wc -l)" \;` work for you?

Comment: Wow! Yes, it works! I tried `$(...)` but it was giving be the same problem of the *backtick*. What does exactly the `  \  ` do? I mean, the `\$(...)` works like a charm.

Comment: They're similar except `$()` can be nested. It's probably my escaping of the dollar sign that gets you out of a situation where the shell you're typing into trying to do the subshell instead of the `sh -c` that gets kicked off for each `find` result.

Comment: Hum... This sounded like Arabic... I guess I need to read something about it (any reference?).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by arabic but [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082?highlight=%28backtick%29) explains backticks versus `$()`. The other part was just me saying that when you don't escape them then the subshell characters are going to be interpreted by the `bash` you're physically typing your command into instead of the one kicked off by `find` which is the behavior you're wanting.

Comment: "Sounds like Arabic" - Italian expression for addressing incomprehensible speech or text. About the interpretation of *subshell characters*, I think I got it. So, basically, what I type into `bash` is executed first by `bash` itself, and then it is sent to the `find`'s `bash`. OK, a bit confusing, but I got it.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes, then you won't have to escape the backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

```
ls -d */ | while read dir; do
    echo "$dir: $(ls $dir | wc -l)"
done
```

When the filenames are numbered without leading zeroes, you can try

```
ls -d */ | cut -d/ -f1 | while read dir; do
     COUNT=$(ls $dir | wc -l);
     echo "$dir: ${COUNT}" ;
     if [ ${COUNT} -gt 10000 ]; then
        ls ${dir}/${dir}?????*.ext | grep -v ${dir}/${dir}10000.ext | xargs rm
     fi
done
```

Another approach would be possible when you have leading zeroes in the filenames:

```
ls -d */ | cut -d/ -f1 | while read dir; do
   ls ${dir}/${dir}*.ext | tail -n +10001 | xargs rm
done
```

Edit:
Included dir+filename in ls commands, and I added `cut -d/ -f1 |` to cut off the trailing /.

Comment: Wow! I believe I want to replace `folderName` with `$dir` and `.ext` with `.*`, right?

Comment: I added the dir in the ls commands.
Your question suggests that you only want to delete files named with extension .ext. When you want all extensions you can replace `.ext` by `.*`.  You can use ${dir}/${dir}* in the last example, but that's not possible with `${dir}?????*.*` (you want to have a minimum number of digits).

Comment: One more question: why did you use `${}` instead of simply `$`? Like `${COUNT}` instead of `$COUNT`.

Comment: Note that this breaks for directory names containing newlines, and directory names containing backslashes, and directory names containing spaces.

Comment: Here $ would be enough. I was used to omit {} when that wouldn't matter and add {} when the variable-name is followed by other characters that could also be part of the var, keeping myself sharp. A colleague said he always used {}, just to be safe and consequent. I decided to change my habbits when I adopted https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml.

Comment: Running your second script gives me some errors (which I reported in the question itself, bottom part).

Comment: @Athold: Nice fix, using seq. Another fix (not tested) would have been `find ${dir} -name "${dir}?????*.*" ! -name "${dir}10000.*" -exec rm {} \;

Comment: I gave up with the `seq` since it was taking forever. I manually removed the 4 folders with 100,000+ files and recreated them with a 10,000 limit. I didn't know the `?` would have work with `find` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes, so that backticks and `$` don't get interpreted by the original shell:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec sh -c 'echo {} $(ls {} | wc -l)' \;
```

For the second question, I would put what you want to do into a separate script, that takes the directory name as an argument. Then do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'acer' -exec ./scriptname {} \;
```

This way you don't have to deal with all the quoting issues from using `-exec sh -c`.

Comment: I thought single and double quotes were interchangeable (like in *lua*). I was wrong. What about the second question? Is there an easier way to delete all the files above the 10,000-th in each and every folder with 10,000+ files named `folderName#.ext`, where `#` > `10000`?

Comment: No, they're like Perl and PHP: single quotes are for strings that should get no interpretation, double quotes are for strings that allow substitution. I'm not sure I understand your second question. Do you want to remove the whole folder, or just all the files after 10,000 within it? I would write a script that does what you want, and then run that script with `-exec`, rather than try to cram everything into a one-liner.

Comment: OK, perhaps I figured out an alternative way. I can `find` every file (within `.`) and then check if the `#` is > `10000`. I guess I have to figure out now how to extract the number from the file name. I'm adding more info to the question above.

Comment: Question updated. Let me know if it is more clear now. OK, I guess I will make a script as you suggest, but I will give up `bash` for `lua`, so at least I know how to move around with strings.

Comment: That should be a new question. Don't mix two different questions in the same post.

Comment: OK. I think you answered both questions. Thank you very much. I will script my way to the solution as you suggested.